# Validate internal web page reference file existance

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf

Are there any validators for Eclipse that checks that internal links between JSF web pages in the same project refers to existing pages?

I realise this is impossible to do in more complex cases, but it should be possible to do in the standard case.

One way to achieve something similar is to create Java constants for all page source files names (for example as properties in an app scoped bean) and reference them from EL, because EL validation checks those. But to do this you have to manually add all the file names which is cumbersome.